# random div content + background

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my code for random `div` `background-image`. I just want to know how to add certain description `div` to each `background`.

```
<div class="slider"></div> 


$(function () {
var url = "http://maispc.com/samuel/content/images/",
    imgArray = [url+"avatar.png",
               url+"provider/blogger.png",
               url+"provider/LinkedIn-32x32.png",
               url+"provider/myspace.png",
               url+"provider/instagram.png",
               url+"provider/Twitter-32x32.png",
               url+"provider/stackoverflow.png",
               url+"provider/Facebook-32x32.png"],
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length)),
    baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";

$(".slider", ".tab").css('background-image', baseUrl);
})();
```

to be like this

```
{ $(function () {
var url = "http://maispc.com/samuel/content/images/",
    imgArray = [url+"avatar.png",
               url+"provider/blogger.png", description div 1
               url+"provider/LinkedIn-32x32.png",description div 2
               url+"provider/myspace.png", and so ....
               url+"provider/instagram.png",
               url+"provider/Twitter-32x32.png",
               url+"provider/stackoverflow.png",
               url+"provider/Facebook-32x32.png"],
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length)),
    baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";

$(".slider").css('background-image', baseUrl);
})();

}
```

Comment: What is a "description div"? Please [edit] your question to explain what the desired behaviour is.

Comment: DO YOU HAVE ANY DESCRIPTION DIV ON EACH SLIDER?

Comment: like a div content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array with all the descriptions.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var url = "http://maispc.com/samuel/content/images/";
    var imgArray = [url+"avatar.png",
               url+"provider/blogger.png",
               url+"provider/LinkedIn-32x32.png",
               url+"provider/myspace.png",
               url+"provider/instagram.png",
               url+"provider/Twitter-32x32.png",
               url+"provider/stackoverflow.png",
               url+"provider/Facebook-32x32.png"];
    var descriptionArray = ["Description 1",
               "Description 2",
               "Description 3",
               "Description 4",
               "Description 5",
               "Description 6",
               "Description 7",
               "Description 8"];
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length));
    var baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";
    var description = descriptionArray[randomNumber];
    $(".slider").css('background-image', baseUrl);
    $(".description").text(description);
})();
```

Comment: what if I want to replace the description attribute from .text to DIV, like this :
(".description").text(description); >>> (".description").div(description);

will it work ? and what shall I change in var descriptionArray and in it's css ?
thanks

Comment: `.div(description);` isn't a function, so it doesn't work. If you wan't to get all divs with class `description` you can do `("div.description").text(description);`. Each item in the descriptionArray has all the descriptions for each corresponding image. For example, if the background image is `avatar.png` the description that would be shown is "description 1". `blogger.png` would have "description 2". So you can change each description based on what image is used. For CSS, I would make sure the text is readable on each image and add a background color to `.description` if it isn't readable.

Comment: well, my content include h2,small text span and then description,

Comment: so can I address them like so

(".h2").text
(".description_small_span").text
(".description").text

Comment: Yes if all of your elements have the same text as the description. Otherwise you will have to create another array for each element.

Comment: hello again @grt812,
if you may help me again, and I really appreciate your response to my question, now I want to add url link to each description div .. I tried it with adding .text but it didn't work and it appeared as text ... 
thanks in advance

Comment: You have to use `.html()` instead because it will include any html and text that you put in. So `$(".description").html(description+"<a href='"+imgArray[randomNumber]+"'>Link to URL</a>");` will give each `.description` the description and a link (anchor tag) with the anchor going to the url of the image.

Comment: Actually I want to add this 
<a class="hey"> and then make
Var hey to each image so this .hey link direct me to a link not the image link

Comment: something like this

var heyArray = ["www,link1.com",
               "www,link1.com/2",
               "www,link1.com/3",
               "www,link1.com/4",
               "www,link1.com/5",
               "www,link1.com/6",
               "www,link1.com/7",
               "www,link1.com/8"];
var hey = heyArray[randomNumber];   
    $(".hey").text(hey);

Comment: `$(".description").html(description+"<a class='hey' href='"+heyArray[randomNumber]+"'>Link to URL</a>");`

Comment: Update:`$(".description").html(description+"<a class='hey' href='"+heyArray[randomNumber]+"'>"+heyArray[randomNumber]+"</a>");` will use javascript to add in each anchor tag.